# Change cursor when hovering over JSplitPane divider

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jsplitpane

I need my cursor to change when i hover over the `JSplitPane` divider. This is purely for improved usability. I discovered two methods to accomplish this. Code shown below

Method 01

```
BasicSplitPaneUI basicSplitPaneUI = (BasicSplitPaneUI)splitPane.getUI();
BasicSplitPaneDivider divider = basicSplitPaneUI.getDivider();
divider.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR));
```

Method 02

```
Component divider = splitPane.getComponent(2);
divider.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR));
```

My problem is, both these methods work as expected if the top container of the `JSplitPane` is a `JFrame` or a `JWindow`. To test, I wrote a small piece of code where the `JSplitPane` is added to a `JPanel` which is then added to a `JFrame`. The cursor changes as expected when hovering over the divider.

But i'm developing a `Tool Window` plugin for intellij and there, the `JSplitPane` (contained within a `JPanel`) is added to a `ToolWindow` container. In this case, the cursor remains the same when i hover over the divider.

Below is some test code I've written to simulate the above scenarios.

Case 01

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //PanelWithSplitPane extends JPanel. Builds the JSplitPane
    PanelWithSplitPane viewer = new PanelWithSplitPane();
    f.add(viewer, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Output: Works as expected. The cursor changes when hovered above the divider

[image]

Case 02: Intellij plugin

note: This is an intellij plugin project, where a `toolWindow` extension is specified in a plugin.xml file. Basically the `createToolWindowContent` method is executed when the tool Window is opened in the IDE. The view and any further user interaction is handled from here.

```
public class TestPane implements ToolWindowFactory {

//this method gets called when the toolWindow is opened in the IDE
@Override
public void createToolWindowContent(Project project, ToolWindow toolWindow) {
   PanelWithSplitPane viewer = new PanelWithSplitPane();
   toolWindow.getComponent().add(panel);
}
}
```

output: Does not work as expected. The cursor remains the same when hovered above the divider

[image]

PanelWithSplitPane code

```
public class PanelWithSplitPane extends JPanel {

public PanelWithSplitPane() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JSplitPane splitPane = new javax.swing.JSplitPane();
    splitPane.setBorder(null);
    splitPane.setDividerLocation(1300);
    splitPane.setDividerSize(6);
    splitPane.setContinuousLayout(true);
    splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);

    BasicSplitPaneUI basicSplitPaneUI = (BasicSplitPaneUI)splitPane.getUI();
    BasicSplitPaneDivider divider = basicSplitPaneUI.getDivider();
    divider.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

    this.add(splitPane);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code where I add the `JPanel` to the `ToolWindow`, and now the setCursor method works as expected. Changes are shown below.

Old variant:

```
    PanelWithSplitPane viewer = new PanelWithSplitPane();
    toolWindow.getComponent().add(panel);
```

New Variant:

```
        PanelWithSplitPane viewer = new PanelWithSplitPane();
        final ContentFactory contentFactory = toolWindow.getContentManager().getFactory();
        final Content content = contentFactory.createContent(viewer, "", true);
        toolWindow.getContentManager().addContent(content);
```

Answer (score 4):

- for example, by using MouseListener and its methods mouseEntered/mouseExited (by returns Cursor back to the default)
- note I'm not able to remove the black rectangle (unwnanted painting artefact created at runtime, when the divider is moved, you can see that at left side)

[image]

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneDivider;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI;

public class JSplitPaneToy {

    private JSplitPane sp;

    public JSplitPaneToy() {
        sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, makePanel(), makePanel());
        /*SplitPaneUI ui = sp.getUI();
         if (ui instanceof BasicSplitPaneUI) {
         ((BasicSplitPaneUI) ui).getDivider().setBorder(null);
         }*/
        BasicSplitPaneUI l_ui = (BasicSplitPaneUI) sp.getUI();
        final BasicSplitPaneDivider l_divider = l_ui.getDivider();
        l_divider.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Dimension l_pane_size = sp.getSize();
                if (sp.getOrientation() == JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT) {
                    int l_new_loc = sp.getDividerLocation() + e.getX();
                    if (l_new_loc >= 0 && l_new_loc <= l_pane_size.width) {
                        sp.setDividerLocation(l_new_loc);
                    }
                } else {
                    int l_new_loc = sp.getDividerLocation() + e.getY();
                    if (l_new_loc >= 0 && l_new_loc <= l_pane_size.height) {
                        sp.setDividerLocation(l_new_loc);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        l_divider.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                l_divider.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                l_divider.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }
        });
        sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        /*sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, makePanel(), sp);
         ui = sp.getUI();
         if (ui instanceof BasicSplitPaneUI) {
         ((BasicSplitPaneUI) ui).getDivider().setBorder(null);
         }
         sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
         sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, makePanel(), sp);
         ui = sp.getUI();
         if (ui instanceof BasicSplitPaneUI) {
         ((BasicSplitPaneUI) ui).getDivider().setBorder(null);
         }
         sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
         sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, makePanel(), sp);
         ui = sp.getUI();
         if (ui instanceof BasicSplitPaneUI) {
         ((BasicSplitPaneUI) ui).getDivider().setBorder(null);
         }
         sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());*/
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSplitPane Toy");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(sp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*try {
         for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
         if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
         javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
         break;
         }
         }
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
         } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
         } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
         }*/
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSplitPaneToy jSplitPaneToy = new JSplitPaneToy();
            }
        });
    }

    private JScrollPane makePanel() {
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(new JTable(
                new Object[][]{{0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}, new Object[]{1, 2, 3}) {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                });
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        return pane;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But this does not work either. Both the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` methods are called correctly, but the `setCursor` method does not seem to work when the top level container is not a JFrame or a JWindow.

Comment: no idea about your issue from Win7, for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, because by calling Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR from mouseExited all Cursors are (in Win10, Java8) correctly painted (DEFAULT_CURSOR for all Rectangle in ContentPane, and it changes to E_RESIZE_CURSOR if I am hover_over its Borders), really no idea about your issue with, because this funcionality works in WInXP / Win7, Win8 and WIn10 quite correctly

Comment: The code you post works fine. The problem is with my intellij tool window plugin. For some reason the `setCursor` method does not work when I add the `JPanel` with the `JSplitPane` to the `ToolWindow` container. I figured out a way to get it working. see my answer